# Haskell RSA encryption

Tags: haskell, encryption, rsa

for an assignment I need to write two function, one to RSA encrypt and one to decrypt.
These functions take the key pair and modulo as parameters.

```
rsaencrypt :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
rsaencrypt (e, m) x = x^e `mod` m

rsadecrypt :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
rsadecrypt (d, m) x = x^d `mod` m
```

Let's suppose we have the key pair (5, 29) with a modulo of 91.
if we want to encrypt the number 75 we get cyphertext 17, if we decrypt 17 we get the 75 back. All good so far.
But when i try a different number, lets say 97. We get cyphertext 41, if we decrypt 41 we get 6.
Why does my function only work on certain numbers?

Comment: Because 97 is basically 6 (mod 91). See here 0 ≤ m < n   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `rsadecrypt`:

```
rsadecrypt (d, m) x = x^d `mod` m
```

It should be clear that all outputs will be between `0` and `m-1` (inclusive). Since decryption definitely sits in that range, you cannot create an encryption for any message outside that range that will exactly round-trip.

...and, to connect the final two dots, `97` is outside the range of `0` to `91-1`, so it cannot be correctly encrypted (for this definition of "correct").